# Primefaces data tables filter records

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF page written with Primefaces components. My page consists of three sectors, each sector contains an accordion panel, and each tab of the accordion contains a data table.

I wish to search the data tables with the two buttons at the top of the sector, "Filter" and "Reset Filters". The search within a sector must be independent from searches within other sectors.

I wish to understand which is the best method to perform the above search/filtering. Consider that every time an accordion tab is opened, the records are loaded from the database.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:tabView id="sectors" value="#{multipleSearchBean.sectors}"
        var="sector">
        <p:tab id="sett" title="#{sector.description}">
            <ui:param name="key" value="searchText#{sector.id - 1}" />
            <p:inputText id="searchValue" value="#{multipleSearchBean[key]}" />

            <p:commandButton id="plainSearch" value="Filter"
                action="#{searchBean.plainSearch()}">
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:commandButton id="resetSearch" value="Reset Filters"
                action="#{searchBean.resetSearchFilters}">
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:accordionPanel id="accordion"
                value="#{searchBean.getTabs()}" var="tab" multiple="true"
                dynamic="true" cache="false"
                activeIndex="#{searchBean.activeIndexes}">
                <p:tab id="accordionTab" title="#{tab.title}">
                    <p:dataTable id="table" var="row"
                        value="#{searchBean.getObjects()}"
                        emptyMessage="Empty table" styleClass="#{sector.id - 1}_tableStyle">
                        <p:column headerText="Code">
                            <h:outputText value="#{row.code}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Description">
                            <h:outputText value="#{row.description}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:tab>
            </p:accordionPanel>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Why do you have a getter method into your table's `value` attribute? The `get` is appended by JSF itself so you only need `searchBean.objects`. Appart from that, it's enough to modify that value in your search methods and update the table to display the proper results.

Comment: It's not so simple. The getted objects depends on a parameter (each accordion tab retrieve different data), so it will be something like `getObjects(param)` and there are three search fields (one for each sector).